# The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly Error

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, composer, checkoutsession

When I try to complete the checkout by paying with Hosted Payment Form (mastercard module) I get an error **400 Bad request**.
I was reading the exception.log file and I found an error that says the following:

**main.CRITICAL: The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly {"exception":"[object]**

I was searching in internet and tried the following commands:

**export COMPOSER_HOME="$HOME/.config/composer/"
export CGR_BASE_DIR="$HOME/.config/composer/global"
export CGR_BIN_DIR="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"**

but none of this worked yet, i'm still getting the error.
Hope someone can help me. 
Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to .htaccess of the store. Add this line at the top of your MagentoRootfolder/.htaccess file

```
SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME COMPOSER_HOME=~/.composer
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem months ago, but yes, it's the right answer!